# Navigating to a new page of application in PLAY framework

Tags: java, jquery, html, templates, playframework

I am working with Play framework 1.2.5. I am trying to load (say) page2 on the click of a button from (say) page1.
On page1 I have a button and I am calling jquery on that button as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#next").click(function(){
            alert("reached jquery")
            $.get("/nextpage");
        });
        });
```

According to me the above code should call URL "/nextpage" from my route file and should go to the mapped method. The code for method is:

```
 public static void Nextpage(){
       Logger.info("reached nextpage method");
       render();
   }
```

Now, my problem is that this method is being hit, also the log in this method is getting printed. I am expecting this method to change the browser URL and render a "Nextpage.html" page on browser but nothing like that happens. The page1 stays as it is. Also no errors from Play side. The logs are printed on console and that is all.

Is something wrong with render() because the code is working properly until just above the render().

Comment: Have you tried using `a href` instead?

Comment: @Mon ...No..As I need to call a backend method on the click from page1 and then accordingly display a page.

Comment: NOT TESTED, but couldn't you replace the `$.get(...)` with something like `window.location.href = "@controllers.App.routes.Nextpage()";` to force an HTTP request? the `jQyery.get()` is a shorthand AJAX request which is why it's not redirecting. This is off the top of my head, I'm not sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not load page content after backend operation via Ajax, instead, just use old good JS redirect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "#next", function(){
        alert("reached jquery")
        window.location.href = "/nextpage";
    });
});
```

Comment: your last rply was helpful but what if I have to redirect to a new page(on a new URL) and also for that page I need some data from server. In that case I will definitely require a $.get call. How to go for that

Comment: Getting response via AJAX and redirecting to some href are quite different things... I can only redirect you to the jQuery API and CAN NOT code for you - too busy... http://api.jquery.com/on/